# Is it possible to get all comments of a Youtube video?

Tags: php, zend-framework, youtube

I am building a web site in PHP that integrates with Youtube. I want to have access to all comments that have been posted on a particular video.

When I use the Zend library, I can get the video comments feed, using the getVideoCommentFeed() method, but that returns only the latest comments.

Is there a way to get every comment that has been posted since the video was uploaded?

If it is not possible, I am considering using a cron job to fetch the comments feed periodically and save them locally, but that would be a last resort solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can only retrieve 25 items per request, but I believe you are able to the next page worth of data by setting the starting comment offset.  Take a look at  [setStartIndex()](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/core/Zend_Gdata/Gdata/Zend_Gdata_Feed.html#setStartIndex) and [setItemsPerPage()](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/core/Zend_Gdata/Gdata/Zend_Gdata_Feed.html#setItemsPerPage).